# MariaDB: Disable the GSSAPI plugin

Tags: mariadb, centos, mariadb-10.1, plugins

How can i disable the GSSAPI plugin? I do not need authentication via Kerberos on my server.

This is my environment:

- Centos 7.3 with SELinux mode enforcing
- MariaDB Server: 10.1.19

In my log file */var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log* i see the next errors:

```
[Warning] GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/locahost.local@' not found in keytab
[ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty.
[ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
```

I cannot find any related to that plugin in the configuration:`enter code here`

```
> SELECT PLUGIN_NAME FROM information_schema.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_TYPE = 'AUTHENTICATION';
+-----------------------+
| PLUGIN_NAME           |
+-----------------------+
| mysql_native_password |
| mysql_old_password    |
+-----------------------+

> SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I only found this configuration file:

- /etc/my.cnf.d/auth_gssapi.cnf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File `/etc/my.cnf.d/auth_gssapi.cnf` contains the line

```
plugin-load-add=auth_gssapi.so
```

Comment it out and restart the service. The server should stop loading the plugin, it will make the errors go away.

If you don't need the plugin at all, you can also uninstall `MariaDB-gssapi` packages

```
MariaDB-gssapi-server-10.1.19-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-gssapi-client-10.1.19-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```